# Help to choose caps for noise filtering

Tags: capacitor, decoupling-capacitor, decoupling

I am trying to build a project with ESP8266. To save PCB space and avoid complexity I have chosen to use Hi-Link's SMPS module for 220V AC- 5V DC conversion. I am bad when it comes to noise / frequency. I have used a 22uF/16V tantalum and a 100nf/6.3V ceramic to deal with the ripples. Below is the schematic. Here is the SMPS module I am referring to http://www.hlktech.net/product_detail.php?ProId=60

C1 and C3 will be close to ESP8266. What I need is a clear and more importantly stable power for the cheap. High ripple may damage the cheap. As this is not an audio circuit, I believe a little noise would be OK. Please suggest.

Am I good with this setup?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you need a very clean DC power for audio, etc, a 100uH  inductor in series with the output cuts ripple by a dramatic amount. The inductor should be rated twice the maximum expected current. You would need a set of capacitors before and after the inductor.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky256, this is not an audio circuit.. As I said using ESP8266. what I need is a clear and more importantly stable power for the cheap. High ripple may damage the cheap. As this is not an audio circuit, I believe little noise would be OK. Please suggest.

Comment: Big caps for low freqency noise and small caps for high frequency noise. I think your setup is fine.

Comment: Chip, not cheap. Chip=component, cheap=low cost

Comment: Ohh, sorry.. typo.. Thanks for pointing though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5V switching power supply has no datasheet but there is information on the web page that says its ripple specification is measured with 10µF // 100nF, so we can safely assume it will be stable and work fine with this amount of capacitance.

They don't say what type of cap is is, but I will assume ceramic since a 10µF electrolytic would have several tens of ohms ESR and be completely useless at ripple filtering anyway.

More capacitance (like your 470µF) will most likely work. A 10µF 16V X7R SMD ceramic cap should work fine too. It will also filter ripple better than an electrolytic due to very low ESR and inductance. If you use a 10µF MLCC it is unnecessary to put a 100nF cap in parallel. You can always put the footprints for both electrolytic and ceramic, and use the one that gives lowest ripple (check with a scope).

The caps at the output of the AMS1117 are another matter, for this you should look at the 1117's datasheet. The 100nF cap at the output is most likely redundant, as there will be at least one ceramic cap on the ESP8266 module PCB, so you can remove it. Ceramic caps have low ESR, so by putting 2 ceramic caps in parallel, with a length of trace or a connector in between acting as an inductor, you risk creating a tuned LC circuit which can resonate.

Now the datasheet says:

> The circuit design used in the AMS1117 series requires the use of
>   an output capacitor as part of the device frequency compensation.
>   The addition of 22µF solid tantalum on the output will ensure
>   stability for all operating conditions.
>   When the adjustment terminal is bypassed with a capacitor to
>   improve the ripple rejection, the requirement for an output
>   capacitor increases. The value of 22µF tantalum covers all cases of
>   bypassing the adjustment terminal. Without bypassing the
>   adjustment terminal smaller capacitors can be used with equally
>   good results.

They don't mention ESR, which is annoying, but solid tantalum caps will have ESR around "one to a few ohms", so you can aim for that. You can also use an aluminium electrolytic cap, if it is a general purpose one you'll need a lot more µF to get the ESR down. The 470µF cap you planned to put on the input of the LDO should work just fine on the output, if you already have it, no need to pay extra for a tantalum.

A similar regulator datasheet says:

> The TLV1117 device is designed to be stable with tantalum and aluminum electrolytic output capacitors having an ESR between 0.2 Ω and 10 Ω.

Also make sure your LDO is properly cooled! Calculate dissipation and  leave enough copper area on the board, connected to the LDO's tab, to suck out the heat.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information :) BTW, the ESP board does not have any cap and thus I have used that 100nf.

Comment: I have added the portion of PCB layout. Can you have a quick look please?

Comment: Very strange that the ESP board has no caps. Are you sure? It can be a tiny ceramic... About the layout: AMS1117 has a tab (pin 4) which is connected to pin 2 internally.  The purpose of the tab is cooling, so it has to be soldered on a large enough copper area. It depends on how much current the ESP8266 will use. So make sure pin 4 is connected to pin 2 in the schematic and add the copper on toplayer. Also there is a large copper pour on the bottom layer but it doesn't seem connected to ground, why?

Comment: Yeah, it is connected to GND..

Comment: But I see that the GND traces are not fully connected with the copper pour. It's only connected where there are vias.. I am new with Altium. Trying to find out how can I remove clearance between GND tracks and the pour.. Regarding the circuit, I am driving some relays directly from the 5V source. So ESP is not really eating much current. So I think it's okay to solder the 4th tab as per the dimension of that pad.

Comment: I see that there are 2 types of polygon connect, direct connect and relief connect. The default is relief connect and thats why the connections are only at the vias. What do you suggest? will be direct connect better?

Comment: "Trying to find out how can I remove clearance between GND tracks and the pour" -> polygon properties dialog: set "pour over same net objects" and it will pour over the tracks. You don't need the tracks if you have a polygon pour, btw. Also check the polygon has the correct net, then repour it.

Comment: "relief connect" makes the pads easier to solder as the copper pour won't suck the heat, so it's good if you don't have a powerful soldering iron.

Comment: Hi, I have made the pads to be relief connect and the vias to be solid contact..

Comment: I am havig hard time to get the 22uF Tantalum for prototyping. If I change that with a 47uF, do you think there could be any issue? here is the reference tech doc http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/40/THJC476_016_JT-262330.pdf

Comment: Increasing the capacitance is ok, it will just make the transient response better. Personally I'd use LM1117 whose datasheet specifies an ESR range for the output cap instead of AMS1117 whose datasheet says nothing at all. LLM1117 says 0.3-22 ohm ESR so this tantalum cap has too little ESR, you need a different one... selecting caps is annoying! I'd just use a panasonic FC 100µF 10V aluminium cap, SMD or thru hole, its ESR is fine and it's cheap.